# How do I get my contact form to work after mod_rewrite?

Tags: forms, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, config

I've built a site using CMS Made Simple. I have to point the host URL for everything EXCEPT the admin page and the contact forms. I was able to successfully do this with mod_rewrite to the config.php and changing up the .htaccess, but now my contact forms are no longer working (one in the footer and one on the contact page). Here is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^energyfa.ipower.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ai/admin/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://accimpress.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

  # 301 Redirect all requests that don't contain a dot or trailing slash to
  # include a trailing slash
  # except for form POSTS
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

  # Rewrites urls in the form of /parent/child/
  # but only rewrites if the requested URL is not a file or directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

Is there a reason my POST exception might not be working? Any suggestions will be much obliged. The website is: http://energyfa.ipower.com/ai/

Thanks,
Cory

Answer (score 1):

try changing your .htaccess from

```
# .htaccess for CMS made simple
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST$
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
# EOF
```

to

```
# .htaccess for CMS made simple
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !$   <--- to put the "/"  ---->
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST$
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]   <--- to put the "/" after } ---->
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
# EOF
```

it work for us

Answer (score 0):

I see that the action on your form is set to http://energyfa.ipower.com/ai/contact-us/.  What I believe will happen is that the POST will go to that URL.  You will hit your first RewriteRule and get redirected to the contact form again, but since it's a browser redirect, it will probably just be a GET, so your POST content never makes it to your script.

Try changing the form action to http://accimpress.com/contact-us/ and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Andrew-- I'll give it a shot. Still having a little trouble locating the actual .php file with that form action info in my CMS.

Comment: @qory If you can't find it, you could also add a RewriteRule at the beginning to create another POST "exception" so that the redirect does not happen.  However, you would then need to ensure that http://energyfa.ipower.com/ai/contact-us/ is a valid location that can process the POST request.

Comment: yes, I've tried that, but it sends to http://energyfa.ipower.com/ai/contact-us/ and gives me Page Not Found. so I don't know how to make it a valid location after I've added that post exception, is there a way?

Comment: @qory If you're desperate and cannot change the form action, you could try putting a PHP script at whatever location http://energyfa.ipower.com/ai/contact-us actually reaches.  Said PHP script could use something like the PHP HTTP library (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php) or cURL to get all the post fields, then create a new POST request to http://accimpress.com/contact-us/.  It's probably going to be much easier just to find and change the form action, though (grep FTW...).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like CMS Made Simple doesn't support their Form Builder module once you've redirected your URL with Pretty URLs, so my solution for now was using Send This File, like so:

http://accimpress.com/upload/

But thanks for your suggestions Andrew!